# How to filter a pattern using Awk and Grep

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to filter nmap results using grep, awk, and sed to create a report. But I can't get just the "178-36-246-126.static." I imagine that i have to have a parameter "xxx-xx-xxx-xx", using these dashes. I tried deleting the first few columns but it affects the bottom rows(`awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$6}'`).
I tried using grep -A and -B but the number of lines is not static. I tried to use sed but the IP numbers vary. It still has over 8000 lines left so I really need some help. Thanks!

```
178-36-246-126.static.xxxxxxxxxx.com (178.36.246.126)
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
178-36-246-134.static.xxxxxxxxxx.com (178.36.246.134)
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
178-36-246-145.static.xxxxxxxxxx.com (178.36.246.145)
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
178-36-246-147.static.xxxxxxxxxx.com (178.36.246.147)
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please do mention your sample of output more clearly in your question. Also what pattern you want to search, please do mention it clearly(rather than putting it xxxx if you can give more meaningful example that will be helpful), cheers.

Comment: I don't understand; what exactly do you want to capture with this example input? Do `sed -n 's/\(.*static\).*/\1/p' test.txt` or `awk '$0 ~ "static" {gsub("static.*", "static"); print $0}' test.txt` provide your expected output?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which rows you want to filter? What the expect output of your sample data?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to remove anything after `static`. on the lines with an IP address. You can change the field separator in awk and then apply pattern matching/replacing for matched lines.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} /^([[:digit:]]{1,3}.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}/ {$0=$1 "." $2} 1'
```

->

```
178-36-246-126.static
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
178-36-246-134.static
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
178-36-246-145.static
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
178-36-246-147.static
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd modify `nmap`'s output options:

```
nmap -oG - subnet/subnetmask | awk '$2~/178-36-246-126.static/ && $4~/Ports:/'
```

Or, even shorter, instead of extracting one hosts information from a subnet scan, just scan that one host with the default output:

```
nmap 178-36-246-126.static
```

Or, if all you're trying to achieve is to strip part of the fully qualified domain-name:

```
nmap subnet/subnetmask | sed 's/\.xxxxxxxxxx\.com//'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to cut off everything after `static`, you can use

```
sed -r 's/^(.*static).*/\1/' file
# or matching better
sed -r 's/^([0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}[.]static).*/\1/' file
Or matching less exact
sed -r 's/^(([0-9]{1,3}[-.]){4}static).*/\1/' file
```

Of course `awk` works fine.
With your input you can use

```
cut -d '.' -f1,2 file
```